# Add a meta tag using jsoup

Tags: jsoup

I wish to add a new meta tag

```
Document doc = Jsoup.parse(.....)
doc.select("meta").first.appendElement("meta".attr("name","henry").attr("content", "ford");
```

gives me

```
<meta name="henry" content="ford" />
</meta>
```

All ok but how can I avoid the second

```
</meta>
```

please.

Comment: doc.select("meta").first().after("meta name=\"henry\" content=\"ford\" />");

Comment: works but not as neat as first one.

Answer (score 8):

You could try this which worked for me.

```
doc.head().appendElement("meta").attr("http-equiv","cache-control").attr("content","no-cache");
```

Hope it helps

Edit:
It looks like you where missing a closing ) after your "meta" appendElement statement.